# Apply MATLAB sscanf to convert from hex to dec for multiple elements in a column vector

Tags: matlab, type-conversion, hex

In MATLAB, I'm trying to convert hex (2’s complement) to decimal for a column vector using the `sscanf` function.  While I have successfully converted using the hex2dec function, however I am unsuccessful converting multiple elements (hex values) in a column vector with `sscanf`. Yet when I have only one element (hex value) in the column vector the hex to dec conversion is successful.  How do you convert a column vector with multiple elements (hex values), using `sscanf` function, to hexadecimal, 2’s complement?

```
colx = ['FEEE'; 'FFFF'; 'FDDD']
conversion = typecast(uint16(sscanf(colx, '%x')), 'int16')
```

My output is:

```
  conversion = -1
```

However the output should be:

```
conversion = -274
             -1
             -547
```

Comment: "While I have successfully converted using the hex2dec function[...]" So use that? Why do you need `sscanf`?

Comment: @Luengo because hex2dec is a lot slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sscanf will linearize the char array into a vector before attempting the conversion.

You need to add some spaces, otherwise it will simply try to convert a big value.  Also, the char array should be transposed since Matlab stores arrays in column major order. In your example, what sscanf actually tries to convert is the string `FFFEFDEFDEFD` which overflows into the maximum value represented by an uint16 (0xFFFF), which itself is the signed integer representation of -1.

Try:

```
colx2 = [colx' ; repmat(' ',1,size(colx,1))]
conversion = typecast(uint16(sscanf(colx2, '%x')), 'int16')
```

The result is:

```
conversion =

   -274
     -1
   -547
```